# how to download and open a doument in myapp in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new in IOS and making an app 
1-First phase download attachment i.e. doc,ppt,and pdfs,xlsx (i hav done with that)
2-Second phase is open those attachment
Please surges me how to open those attachments

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use UIDocumentInterationController . [Tutorial for Opening the Documents](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)